# Swift: Unable to chain DispatchGroup

Tags: swift

I am attempting to chain two dispatchGroups but my code is always crashing at random places.

My function is as such:

```
func getAllActivities(userUID: String, _ completionHandler: @escaping (_ activities: [ActivitiesForUIStruct]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    let downloadGroup = DispatchGroup()
    let detailGroup = DispatchGroup()

    let _ = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)

    var activities = [ActivitiesForUIStruct]()

    getActivities(userUID: userUID) { (results, error) in
        //Handle error

        downloadGroup.enter()
        if let results = results {
            var groupTitle = ""
            var originatorName = ""
            var sourceName = ""

            results.forEach({ (activity) in
                let originatorUID = activity.originatorUserUID ?? ""
                let groupID = activity.inspectionGroupID ?? ""
                let sourceID = activity.sourceID ?? ""

                detailGroup.enter()
                self.getTitle(key: "inspectionGroups", value: groupID, { (title, error) in
                    ...

                    if let title = title {
                        groupTitle = title
                        detailGroup.leave()
                    }
                })

                detailGroup.enter()
                self.getName(userUID: originatorUID, { (name, error) in
                    ...

                    if let name = name {
                        originatorName = name
                        detailGroup.leave()
                    }
                })

                detailGroup.enter()
                self.getTitle(key: "users", value: sourceID, { (title, error) in
                    ... 

                    if let title = title {
                        sourceName = title
                        detailGroup.leave()
                    }
                })

                detailGroup.notify(queue: .global(qos: .userInitiated), execute: {
                    let activityUI = ActivitiesForUIStruct(activities: activity, originatorName: originatorName, sourceName: sourceName, inspectionGroupTitle: groupTitle)
                    activities.append(activityUI) //crash here
                    downloadGroup.leave() //crash here
                })
            })
        }

        downloadGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
            completionHandler(activities, nil)
        })
    }
}
```

The aim of my code is to grab the name and title from the UID, and then append it to a customized `struct`. However, my implementation tends to crash at the areas as marked in the `detailGroup.notify`. Would anybody advice where have I gone wrong?

Note: my function calls are correct, ie I am able to print out the `originatorName`, `sourceName` and `groupTitle`.

Comment: One problem I can see is that you always `enter` but you don't always `leave`. Take the `self.getTitle` completion block for example: if `title`is nil, `leave()` will not be called. Better use a `defer { detailGroup.leave() }` so that no matter how you leave the completion block, `leave` will be called.

Comment: @CodeDifferent thanks for picking that up. I have added `else detailGroup.leave()` when `title` is nil. But it doesn't change the end results. I am still crashing at the same places as commented in my question.

Comment: With your code `downloadGroup.leave()` is called more times than `downloadGroup.enter()`.

Comment: @OOPer And that's exactly where the crash is :-)

Comment: @OOPer I just tried to shift the `downloadGroup.enter()` to just after the `forEach` statement but it still crashes. Otherwise, where should I leave or enter?

Comment: What happens when you move all `detailGroup.enter()` before `self.getTitle..` ?

Comment: @OOPer Don quite understand, aren't all `detailGroup.enter()` already before `self.getTitle`?

Comment: You have two `getTitle`, I mean the first one.

Comment: @OOPer just tried. Same results, but now it crashes mostly at the `activities.append()`.

Comment: How about using `.main` for `detailGroup.notify(queue:` ?

Comment: @OOPer SOLVED!! Thank you!! <3 Pls post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: OK, I will write an answer with explanation why you need it. Please check it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### First,

you need to balance `enter()` and `leave()`. Your code calls `downloadGroup.enter()` only once out of the `results.forEach`, but `downloadGroup.leave()` is called inside the loop multiple times. So, if the `results` has two or more elements, `downloadGroup.leave()` is called more times than `downloadGroup.enter()`.

---

#### Second,

Some seemingly asynchronous method may call completion handler synchronously. (For example, when cache hits.) So, some `detailGroup.leave()` may be called before `detailGroup.enter()`.

```
detailGroup.enter() +1
detailGroup.leave() 0  --> detailGroup.notify fires!
detailGroup.enter() +1
detailGroup.leave() 0  --> detailGroup.notify fires!
detailGroup.enter() +1
detailGroup.leave() 0  --> detailGroup.notify fires!
```

(`detailGroup.notify` fires each time internal count gets `0`.)

As shown above, this may cause `detailGroup.notify` fire multiple times. To make `detailGroup.notify` fire only once when all tasks finished, you need to guarantee all `detailGroup.enter()` executed before any `detailGroup.leave()`.

```
detailGroup.enter() +1
detailGroup.enter() +2
detailGroup.enter() +3
detailGroup.leave() +2
detailGroup.leave() +1
detailGroup.leave() 0  --> detailGroup.notify fires!
```

---

#### Third,

Swift `Array` is not thread safe. So, if your `activities` can be updated in multiple-threads, that may cause unexpected behavior including crash. Better update such an Array in a UI thread.

---

All theses things considered, your code would look like something like this:

```
func getAllActivities(userUID: String, _ completionHandler: @escaping (_ activities: [ActivitiesForUIStruct]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    let downloadGroup = DispatchGroup()
    let detailGroup = DispatchGroup()

    var activities = [ActivitiesForUIStruct]()

    getActivities(userUID: userUID) { (results, error) in
        //Handle error

        if let results = results {
            var groupTitle = ""
            var originatorName = ""
            var sourceName = ""

            results.forEach({ (activity) in
                //### 1. Balance enter() and leave()
                downloadGroup.enter()

                let originatorUID = activity.originatorUserUID ?? ""
                let groupID = activity.inspectionGroupID ?? ""
                let sourceID = activity.sourceID ?? ""

                //### 2. Guarantee all enter() executed before leave()
                detailGroup.enter() //for getTitle(key: "inspectionGroups"...
                detailGroup.enter() //for getName(userUID: originatorUID...
                detailGroup.enter() //for getTitle(key: "users"...

                self.getTitle(key: "inspectionGroups", value: groupID, { (title, error) in
                    //...
                    if let title = title {
                        groupTitle = title
                    }
                    detailGroup.leave()
                })

                self.getName(userUID: originatorUID, { (name, error) in
                    //...
                    if let name = name {
                        originatorName = name
                    }
                    detailGroup.leave()
                })

                self.getTitle(key: "users", value: sourceID, { (title, error) in
                    //...
                    if let title = title {
                        sourceName = title
                    }
                    detailGroup.leave()
                })

                //### 3. Use main queue to safely modify thread-unsafe objects
                detailGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
                    let activityUI = ActivitiesForUIStruct(activities: activity, originatorName: originatorName, sourceName: sourceName, inspectionGroupTitle: groupTitle)
                    activities.append(activityUI)
                    downloadGroup.leave()
                })
            })
        }

        downloadGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
            completionHandler(activities, nil)
        })
    }
}
```

In some conditions, some of my suggestions might not be needed, but you should better have all 3 (+1 suggested by Code Different) things in mind when woking with DispatchGroup or asynchronous tasks.